# Git: How to rebase and squash "Merge remote-tracking branch" to the later commit?

Tags: git

I've created a pull request which has the commits as shown below. However, I am required to rebase the **Merge remote-tracking branch 'original/master' into avsp** commit.

*git log output*

```
commit eb4b301a88f02adccecdc09b82e4fc4a12656d34 (HEAD -> avsp, origin/avsp)
Author: Nikhil P <nikhilap@blah.com>
Date:   Thu May 2 20:26:45 2019 -0700

    Address some review comments

commit 0ba34d2145688c133152e7db1d8bf29f503ab34c
Merge: 5e7c1a31 beacedb0
Author: Nikhil P <nikhilap@blah.com>
Date:   Thu May 2 00:32:02 2019 -0700

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'original/master' into avsp

commit beacedb0b2b2e4ceb1b8b626b94f66ba592356a4
Author: Guy Harris <guy@alum.mit.edu>
Date:   Wed May 1 00:23:08 2019 -0700

    Remove the IPv6 payload length checks for checksumming.

    If there isn't an IPv6 payload, there isn't any TCP or UDP packet, and
    there's no TCP or UDP header to checksum, so there's no need for the
    check (it's not there for IPv4).
```

*Expected git log*

```
commit eb4b301a88f02adccecdc09b82e4fc4a12656d34 (HEAD -> avsp, origin/avsp)
Author: Nikhil P <nikhilap@blah.com>
Date:   Thu May 2 20:26:45 2019 -0700

    Address some review comments

commit beacedb0b2b2e4ceb1b8b626b94f66ba592356a4
Author: Guy Harris <guy@alum.mit.edu>
Date:   Wed May 1 00:23:08 2019 -0700

    Remove the IPv6 payload length checks for checksumming.

    If there isn't an IPv6 payload, there isn't any TCP or UDP packet, and
    there's no TCP or UDP header to checksum, so there's no need for the
    check (it's not there for IPv4).
```

I tried to rebase and squash the last 2 commits into 1 so I tried

> git rebase -i HEAD~2

This resulted in around ~450 commits

```
  1 pick 111e17e8 Don't use CMAKE_C_STANDARD, it doesn't work on all versions of CMake.
  2 pick 32f8eded Initialize C_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS where we start setting it.
   ** Snipped 400 more commits here ** 
451 pick beacedb0 Remove the IPv6 payload length checks for checksumming.
452 pick eb4b301a Address some review comments
```

Now when try to pick the *eb4b301a* commit and squash the rest, I see this error below:

```
error: cannot 'squash' without a previous commit
You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'.
Or you can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.
```

If it is not possible to rebase, is it possible to simply delete the commit from the commit history? Would there be a side effect because of that?

Comment: Did you try to initiate the rebase via commit id? Like this: `git rebase -i beacedb0b2b2e4ceb1b8b626b94f66ba592356a4`

Comment: this is not an answer but a suggestion, when ever you are going to perform complicated git command and you don't know is going to happen, then try them on some online git playground. they show everything going to happen in UI. i am new to git and i use these site to learn and practice. specially http://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/ and https://learngitbranching.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

1) To perform a squash operation in an interactive rebase, you need to have a parent commit of the commit being squashed. The reason being - commit being squashed gets squashed in to the parent commit :)

Hence, you can not squash the last commit as it does not have a commit to be squashed in to.

In your case, if you put

```
451 squash beacedb0 Remove the IPv6 payload length checks for checksumming.
452 pick eb4b301a Address some review comments
```

you will be able to rebase.

2) I guess you will be able to get rid of the merge commit just by performing an interactive rebase without doing any specific operation. Try doing this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

It will show up 450+ commits because of the merge commit and present a list to pick/squash/delete.

Do not change any operation and proceed [ESC + :wq in case of Windows OS].
Now once it says Successfully rebased, check git log.

Comment: Why is it not adviseable to remove a merge commit where a branch was merged you now want to rebase on?

Comment: Making the merge commit disappear through a rebase is not problematic at all. But deleting the merge commit is. As merge commit has at least two trees, deleting/reverting it would probably mean getting rid of one of the trees. I'm not sure how comfortably it can be done.

Comment: "Deleting" is a very misleading term here and should be avoided; "deleting" a commit is hardly possible in git. I agree that one should be careful when reverting a merge commit. But OPs question was about (interactive) rebasing, so I do not see the necessity for your first point.

Comment: Yes, deleting a commit is misleading. To avoid the confusion, I got rid of that part in the answer. Hoping that OP will understand from comments that it's a riskier option to revert a merge commit.

Comment: I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~2` without changing any operation but it resulted in bunch of conflicts when rebasing. Saw this when 350 commits had been re-based